# Filter a JavaScript array for elements greater zero

Tags: javascript, arrays

I’ve got a "2D"-JavaScript array, holding these kind of data:

```
let arr = [
    ["w",0],
    ["x",1],
    ["y",0],
    ["z",2]
]
```

I would like to remove all rows that contain a 0 for their second item, so that the resulting array would look like this:

```
arr = [
    ["x",1],
    ["z",2]
]
```

Any elegant thoughts?

Comment: You could try using `.filter`, maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.filter()` where you can check the inner array do not contain element value `0` on second position by `item[1] !== 0`:

```js
let arr = [
    ["w",0],
    ["x",1],
    ["y",0],
    ["z",2]
];
var res = arr.filter(item => item[1] !== 0);
console.log(res);
```

Using `filter()` you can loop through each element of the array and pass that element in a callback function which then return the same/modified element based on the condition. So, `item` is the element of the array and this is passed to a callback function. Since, we have only one line code in callback we can replace that callback function with `item[1] !== 0` and it also return by default when the condition is satisfied.

Comment: @McTell added more description in answer

Comment: You could miss out the whole `!== 0` bit if you wanted as 0 is falsey

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `Array.prorotype.filter` and array destructuring assignment:

```
let arr = [
    ["w",0],
    ["x",1],
    ["y",0],
    ["z",2]
]

const filtered = arr.filter(([_,a]) => a > 0);

console.log(filtered);
```